# GPS coordinate of center of a grid

Tags: grids-graticules, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, agriculture

I am working on a project to identify weeds.  I used the grid to separate the area.  Each cell is marked weed or no weed.
I would like to get the GPS of the center of each cell with a weed in it.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
We ultimately hope to upload the coordinates to a drone and have it spray each marked grid.
[image]

Comment: `I used the grid to separate the area.`  How is the grid defined? `I would like to get the GPS of the center of each cell` I assume you mean coordinate?

Comment: Defined?  Not sure.  I just used the grid tool 1 X 1 meter.  The spray area of the drone is 5 X 5 m so I will use that in the future.  Coordinate yes.  I almost got it.  I used "extract feature by selection" on the grid with the weed points using NUMPINTS > 0.  This selected all grids with weeds present.  Then I added centroid to each of the selected grids.  Then I used the "Add coordinates to points" tool.  The cooridnates are in some weird format.  Is there a way to change it to GPS?  Thank you.

Comment: By defined I meant ~ Do you know the geographic coordinates of the bounding box of the grid, was/is it based on some projection, how big are the cells (OK you answered that).~  You should edit the question to add the details

Comment: You mean you want to know the latitude and longitude of the points you have now created?  If so, what software are you using?

Comment: Using QGIS.  The point is right in the center of each cell with a weed in it.  I would like to get latitude and longitude yeah.  Thank you

Comment: Side question.  Why can I not add any more picture?  They all say to large even though they are the same size as the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use: `QgsCoordinateTransform(src_crs,dest_crs, QgsProject.instance())` where src_crs is the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` of you layer and dest_crs the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` of WGS84.

Comment: Im new to QGIS.  Can you give me simple step by step instructions?  Is that a tool I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
prj = QgsProject.instance()
dest_crs= QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")#WGS84
src_crs= prj.crs()
transformation = QgsCoordinateTransform(src_crs, dest_crs, prj)

yourPoint = QgsPoint(QgsPoint(994369,515288))#example coords
yourPoint.transform(transformation)
print(yourPoint.x(), "/", yourPoint.y())
```

will return 21.3538857925002 / 48.260682704154206